# Is /etc/resolv.conf useful during DNS Referrals or Zone Transfers

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I have just started working on DNS Referrals and I was going through a Link to Understand what are DNS Referral Queries
[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24383/what-is-a-recursive-dns-query][1]

The 3. Point here talks about

```
OS: Sure thing...

Hmm. It's not in my own hosts file. Lemme just check my resolver configuration...
```

Is this talking about the hosts /etc/resolv.conf?

If yes, How is the /etc/resolv.conf useful to making DNS Referrals? 
If no, Could we use /etc/resolv.conf to make DNS Referrals or Zone Transfers?

Could I get some links on how /etc/resolv.conf works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resolv.conf` has nothing to do with either of those. It is used by the operating system's built-in stub resolver to find the *initial* server to talk with. (It is similar in purpose to "root hints".)

- DNS referrals are used by *recursive* resolvers which start from `.` root, then go through each level until they reach the final domain.
- The operating system only has a *stub* resolver which does not understand referrals. It only talks to one server, and always expects a full answer.
- DNS zone transfers are done between two authoritative servers (i.e. hosting the same domain). They are not used by resolvers at all.

In other words, `/etc/resolv.conf` is where you specify which DNS servers to use on Linux or BSD, exactly like [this dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0HhQ.png) on Windows. For example it'd have the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to use Google Public DNS.